# How can I make a printf function in c for my operating system without stdio?

Tags: c, operating-system

I wanted to make a basic operating system in c and I wanted to make a printf
function.

```
void printf(char* str){
    (unsigned short*) VideoMemory = (unsigned short*) 0xb800;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}

kmain()
{   
    printf("Hello from kernel.");
}
```

But when I compile it I get this error:

kernel.c:3:20: error: ‘VideoMemory’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  (unsigned short*) VideoMemory = (unsigned short*) 0xb800;

Comment: Just a typo: `unsigned short* VideoMemory = (unsigned short*) 0xb800;`

Comment: `(unsigned short*) VideoMemory = (unsigned short*) 0xb800;` is parsed as _cast `VideoMemory` to `unsigned short*` and assign the right hand side to the result_, if you're wondering why the compiler can't figure that out.

Comment: Your `printf` function is rather a basic [`puts`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to target a real mode PC BIOS system.  Your definition for `VideoMemory` is incorrect. If your compiler uses 32-bit pointers in flat mode, try this:

```
void printf(char *str) {
    unsigned short *VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000UL;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}

void kmain() {   
    printf("Hello from kernel.");
}
```

Otherwise, with 16 bit ints and segmented pointers, you may need to use the `far` or `__far` keyword such as:

```
unsigned short far* VideoMemory = (unsigned short far*)0xb8000000UL;
```

Note that it is a bad idea to define your own version of `printf` with different semantics than the standard function.  It creates confusion among programmers and the compiler might perform incorrect optimizations, such as converting `printf` calls to something else.  Call this function `kputstr` until you can make it handle formatting with variable argument lists, at which time you will rename it `kprintf`.

Comment: I'd say even `kprintf()` would be a bad name for a function that cannot format anything. Something like `kstrout()` or maybe `kputstr()` would be more descriptive.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I agree, as long as the function does not handle formatting, it should not bear the `printf` mark.  The OP needs substantial work to get this working, but it is a very good project to learn C programming.

Comment: This cause a Segmentation faults.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: what is your target system? what tool chain do you use?
 how do you test your work??

Comment: GCC with  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS i686 CPU

Comment: @EsmaeelE you're aware this pointer is only meaningful in real mode (iow for something running on a PC *without* a kernel/os in place)?

Comment: @FelixPalmen did you know how i can examine it on my system

Comment: @FelixPalmen That's only half the truth... Provided that the system is in the correct video mode (standard 80x25, no fb etc) you can map the physical memory at 0xb8000 from /dev/mem and use it like in real mode

Comment: The source code of my operating system is on github: https://github.com/PixelDevelopers/PDOS

Comment: void printf(char *str) {
    unsigned short *VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}

kmain()
{ 
 printf("Hello from kernel.");
}